# Colocando um produto em uma categoria existente

Tags: java, spring

Estou tendo problema para salvar um produto com uma categoria ja existente. Fiz um metodo que salva o produto e chama a categoria para o produto entrar na categoria, mas depois do "Optional category = categoryRepository.findById(e.getId());" nao consigo ter acesso ao "category.getProducts".

> ERRO DE COMPILACAO

**java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
lower bounds: com.home.prodCate.models.Category,java.lang.Object
lower bounds: java.util.Optional<com.home.prodCate.models.Category>.**

```
Product save(Product product) {
    product.setName(product.getName());
    product.getCategories().addAll(product.getCategories()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> {
                Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(e.getId());
                category.getProducts().add(product); //AQUI O ERRO
                return category;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return productRepository.save(product);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

O problema e que no map

```
map(e -> {
                Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(e.getId());
                category.getProducts().add(product); //AQUI O ERRO
                return category;
            })
```

Note que vc esta retornando um Category

e esta persistindo no productRepository, seria legal melhorar a modelagem

1 - Acho legal criar uma tabela de relacionamento categoria produto

2 - Persistir o objeto CategoriaProduto